# Multiple findForPassport ? e.g Login with username and phone number

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

I have tried findForPassport. It is good if there is just one field instead of the default but I want to log in either with username or phone number.

For the basic login what I did is

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');

        $this->username = $this->findUsernameOrPhone();
    }

public function findUsernameOrPhone()
    {
        $login = request()->input('username');

        $fieldType = Str::startsWith($login, '07') ? 'phone' : 'username';

        request()->merge([$fieldType => $login]);

        return $fieldType;
    }

/**
     * Get phone property.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Get username property.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
```

Comment: Let me say more about the title, I want to login in laravel-passport (API) with username or phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this into t=your user model. here $username can be username or email

```
public function findForPassport($username) {
        return $this->orWhere('username', $username)
        ->orWhere('email',$username)->first();
}
```